# Error de hooks al crear sistema de importación de rutas en APP.js de react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Buenas tengo un proyecto con create-react-app (con hooks) en el que tengo las rutas una archivo `./routes` con una constante que es un array con objetos (path de la ruta y componente)

Estoy tratando de importar esa constante en mi `app.jsx` para mapearlo y que funcionen las rutas, pero me da un error y no encuentro la solución.

El error que me da es relacionado con los hooks de useState etc... de los componentes de las rutas. Me dice que no se puede usar un hook dentro de un componente "hijo". Entiendo que es un problema de los hooks de los componentes que al importarlos de esta forma me los pone como hijos.

PD: si monto las rutas de forma "tradicional" en el app.jsx todo funciona perfecto, es al montar esta estructura de rutas en una constante que falla.
Este es el `./routes/index.jsx`

```
import Register from "../pages/Authentication/Register";
import ForgetPwd from "../pages/Authentication/ForgetPassword";


const staticRoutes = [
{ path: "/forgot-password", component: ForgetPwd },
{ path: "/register", component: Register }
]
```

Este es el app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {staticRoutes} from './routes'

function App() {
  return (
   <Router>
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          {staticRoutes.map((route, idx) => <Route path={route.path}>{route.component}</Route>}                       
       </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Tienes un typo en `=> <Route path={route.path}>{route.componen</Route>`, te falta cerrar los corchetes, y la t de "component"

Comment: @FranAcuna al copiar el código aquí se me ha olvidado, en el código real está bien. Ja he editado la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el problema es por que el componente se carga aun cuando no esta en uso, algo para ayudar a generar tus rutas es el uso de [`lazy`](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) por lo que tu `staticRoutes` puede quedar de la siguiente manera.

```
const staticRoutes = [
{ path: "/forgot-password", component: lazy(() => import ("../pages/Authentication/ForgetPassword"))},
{ path: "/register", component: lazy(() => import("../pages/Authentication/Register"))}
]
```

Tu `route` podría quedar de la siguiente manera, esto a modo de ejemplo y basado en lo que indica el ejemplo de la [documentación de react](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy), pero con esto debería quedar solucionado tu problema.

```
{staticRoutes.map((route) => (
    <Route path={route.path}>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <section>
          <route.component />
        </section>
      </Suspense>
    </Route>
))}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ha funcionado perfectamente.